# Hardware upgrade: hardware vs software RAID

Tags: upgrade, raid

I've decided to upgrade my system disk (Ubuntu 12.04) from a 7200 RPM EIDE HDD to a SSD.  But my motherboard only supports 2 SATA drives, which are already allocated to a RAID-1 array.  Clearly, I have to add a SATA controller, but if I'm going to do that, would it make more sense to implement a hardware RAID instead of doing in software as I'm doing now?  Are there any controllers that are particularly recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no advantages to fake RAID or expensive real hardware RAID controllers that I know of.

The [advantage of software RAID](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Linux_Raid#Hardware_RAID) is that your RAID sets are not dependent on a certain controller or format and that you receive bugfixes and software updates easily through the software update process.